# Docker build is stuck on Building when the Server starts

Tags: docker, flask, containers

I am trying to build a docker image with the following command `docker build -t albums .`

using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY albums ./albums
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
RUN flask --app albums run
```

However, the build is stuck like when executing the last line of the Dockerfile:

```
(app) david@Davids-MacBook-Pro app % docker build -t albums .
[+] Building 24.1s (9/10)                                                                                                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3                                                                                                  6.7s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/python:3@sha256:1db68f83ca0d2735aeb804708cbc2b7be573ff4c236b2bbfa220bbac81512bb8                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 3.84kB                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] COPY albums ./albums                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [4/6] COPY requirements.txt .                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [5/6] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt                                                                                          0.0s
 => [6/6] RUN flask --app albums run                                                                                                                        17.2s
 => => #  * Serving Flask app 'albums'                                                                                                                           
 => => #  * Debug mode: off                                                                                                                                      
 => => # WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.                                  
 => => #  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000                                                                                                                     
 => => # Press CTRL+C to quit
```

The image never finishes getting created. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Just had to change the last line to:

CMD [ "flask", "--app" , "albums", "run", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80", "--no-reload"]